# Why does this div go behind another div in this short code?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I suspect knowing why it is happening but I need expert knowledge on this issue to fix it because I need to keep the background-image...

I have this first parent div with his children:

```
<div id="wtf" style="margin-top:5%; display:block; float:left; width:auto; height:auto; background:whitesmoke;">
                          <div style="width:33%;">
                              <div class="block">
       some content    

                              </div>
                              </div>


                          <div style="float:left; width:33%;">
                                <div class="block">
some content                   

                                </div></div>




                               <div style="float:left; width:33%;">
                                <div class="block">
       some content       


                                </div></div> 



                          </div>
```

Right after there is this div that is supposed to be transposed but instead this div goes hiding behind the first one. I suspect it is because the div does not contain any solid object since it only has a background as image instead of `img`:

```
<div id="banner_index" class="animated fadeIn">
           <br><br>
           <span class="banner_message">
   some msg
           </span>

            <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>


           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

          <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>



              <a href="category?${category.id}" class="banner_button"><fmt:message key='SOMEKEY'/></a>


       </div>
```

The CSS:

```
    #banner_index{
    border-bottom:2px solid whitesmoke;
    width:100%;
    min-height:700px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-image: url("../images/category/478969.jpg");
background-color:black;
    color:whitesmoke;
}

    .banner_message{
        font-size:x-large;
        padding:1%;
        font-family:print clearly;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display:block;

    }
```

Comment: how does your Output look like ?

Comment: @Webruster: the `#banner_index` goes hiding behind the `#wtf` div and that particular #wtf div stops where the `spans` start as if it ignores the first part of the `#banner_index` because of the background.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/pvf9c91x/)

Comment: @Webruster: Precisely yes but this technique makes the background-image disappear why? :S

Comment: ok you wat `black background` under `white smoke`?

Comment: Yes I want `black background` under `white smoke` but the image in `black background` disappears when `black background` is `clear:both`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91351/discussion-between-webruster-and-jane-nice).

Comment: @Webruster: Hey it works. I solved the mystery of the disappeared background-image! It was just a bug for some reason the image disappeared from the folder. Make your answer official and I'll give the reputation to you!

Comment: Sure will do that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left: -159px;margin-top: 16px;` to the `div` Here is the Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/pvf9c91x/)

Answer (score 1):

**Hi now define your** `#banner_index` `clear` `both;` and `#wtf{width:100%;}`

```
#banner_index{clear:both;}
```

```css
#wtf{width:100%;}        
#banner_index{
    border-bottom:2px solid whitesmoke;
    width:100%;
      clear:both;
    min-height:700px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-image: url("../images/category/478969.jpg");
background-color:black;
    color:whitesmoke;
}

    .banner_message{
        font-size:x-large;
        padding:1%;
        font-family:print clearly;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display:block;

    }
```

```html
<div id="wtf" style="margin-top:5%; display:block; float:left;  height:auto; background:whitesmoke;">
                          <div style="width:33%;">
                              <div class="block">
       some content    

                              </div>
                              </div>


                          <div style="float:left; width:33%;">
                                <div class="block">
some content                   

                                </div></div>




                               <div style="float:left; width:33%;">
                                <div class="block">
       some content       


                                </div></div> 



                          </div>

<div id="banner_index" class="animated fadeIn">
           <br><br>
           <span class="banner_message">
   some msg
           </span>

            <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>


           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

           <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>

          <span class="banner_message">
            some msg
           </span>



              <a href="category?${category.id}" class="banner_button"><fmt:message key='SOMEKEY'/></a>


       </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It only solved part of the problem. `clear: both` did transposed the `#banner_index`. However it made the background disappeared.